# Trigger event when dynamically generated image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I trigger an event when a dynamically generated image is clicked?

```
<body>
    <!-- this img element is dynamically generated after page load -->
    <img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/x-4KLOsfkHw/hqdefault.jpg">
</body>
```

I thought this would work:

```
$('body').delegate('.youtube-thumb').on('click', function(){
    console.log('hi')
})
```

But this triggers the event when I click anywhere in the `body`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of the `delegate()` method is incorrect, try this:

```
$('body').delegate('.youtube-thumb', 'click', function(){
    console.log('hi')
});
```

That said, you should be using `on()` instead as `delegate()` is considered outdated. Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.youtube-thumb', function(){
    console.log('hi')
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should be like following. `delegate()` function is not needed.

```
$('body').on('click', '.youtube-thumb', function(){
    console.log('hi')
})
```